# Website redirect setting for https:// prefixed naked domain

Tags: https, dns

I have a site registered on Google Domains and deployed on an Azure VM,  HTTPS enforced via the IIS webconfig file. It all works fine, except for 1 piece:

`https://mywebsite.com`  results in "this page cannot be displayed, mywebsite.com unexpectedly closed the connection."

`https://www.mywebsite.com` works fine, as does the unsecure naked domain redirect (`http://mywebsite.com`; it redirects to the `https://www` prefixed link, I have set this up this Permanent redirect in Google domains).

Given the above, what setting (on my Azure VM SSL binding, or Google Domains, more likely) could I change to make sure if someone types in `https://mywebsite.com`, they will reach it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a binding listening on port 443 to mywebsite.com? This should solve the issue.

cheers

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply - I am not really sure how to check for this; do you know how I would set it up in Azure (using  a Web Service app)?

Comment: In Azure WebApps you can add custom domains and SSL certificates, when you assign an SSL certificate to a domain your app is listening on port 443. When you add the custom domain the DNS records you need to make are shown.